# Why the calculation of deltas doesn't work?

Tags: matlab, sum

Please see my script here:

```
T = importdata('data_jana.xls');

result = cell(1, size(T,2));
for icol = 1:size(T,2);
    nzeros = 0;
    delta = 0;
    deltas = [];
    for el = T(:, icol);
        if el==0
            nzeros = nzeros + 1;
            if nzeros==5
                deltas = [deltas, delta];
                delta = 0;
            end
        else
            delta = delta + el;
            nzeros = 0;

        end
    end
    if nzeros<5
        deltas = [deltas, delta];
        delta = 0;
    end
    disp(deltas);
    result{icol} = deltas;
end
```

I don't understand why deltas are not calculated using this script... Can someone help me? Thanks.

En example of what I want:

```
col1= [0.2 , 0.2 , 0 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2]
result_col1= [1.0, 0.6, 1.0].
```

Comment: What is the current result ? What result are you expecting ?

Comment: In my result file, I have only imported datas. I need to have the sum of successive values respecting this rule  "if you have five or more 0 consecutively, you stop the calculation of deltas. if you have less than five 0, you continue".

Comment: Can you give one or two examples of an input array `T` and what you expect the `result` array to hold after the script is run? For example, what should `result` be if `T = [ 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 10 ]'`?

Comment: Please update the question, do not add code as a comment.

Comment: Thomas, with your example the result is 15, 24.

Comment: Your nested `for` loop is incorrect. just delete the `for` and `end` statements and it should work.

Comment: @Adriaan, I have removed 'for' loops and the problem is still here, the deltas calculation is not made. I have now an error message 'The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.'

Comment: Hmm, yea, apologies. `el` will be set to all values on the corresponding row in `T`. You are overwriting `nzeros` as soon as you encounter something which is not zero, is it supposed to do that? (e.g. `nzeros = nzeros+0;`) rest should be working. Can you post a sample of `T` (first few rows), so we can test it ourselves?

Comment: @Adriaan, yes exactly. I have edit my question and post one example of what I have and what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop over `el` is incorrect.

Replace:

```
for el = T(:, icol);
```

with these two lines:

```
for r = 1:numel(T(:, icol))
    el = T(r, icol);
```

Using

```
T = [0.2 , 0.2 , 0 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0 , 0 , 0.2 , 0.2].';
```

I get

```
>> result
result =
{
  [1,1] =

     1.00000   0.60000   1.00000

}
>> result{1}
ans =

   1.00000   0.60000   1.00000
```